# The meaning of notion

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've found the following possible meanings of the noun *notion*:

> 1. A belief or opinion
> 2. A mental image
> 3. An impulse or whim
> 4. a vague idea; impression
> 5. an idea, concept, or opinion
> 6. an inclination or whim

But what could it mean in the following sentence:

> This man posseses of some radical notions.

Comment: @Man_From_India Here is a context __It belongs to a man I met in half-remember dream. This man possesed of some radical notintions.__

Comment: A bit more about the context: I think it's from *Inception*. In the opening of *Inception*, Saito said, "I know what this is. I have seen one before, many, many years ago. It belonged to a man I met in a half-remembered dream... A man possessed of some radical notions." -- @Man_From_India I think you're right that it's about "radical idea". Though IMHO, movie scripts are usually written in such a way that allows us to interpret the dialogue in more than one way, even simultaneously. (Text vs. subtext is common in books, movies, poems, lyrics, etc.)

Comment: So if that is in fact the text you meant, you have misquoted it.  "in half-remember dream" s/b "in a half-remembered dream".  "posseses of" s/b "possessed of".  this passive voice "possessed of" means "possessed" (no "of").  So the man had some radical ideas.  Sense 2 in http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/radical?s=t

Answer (score 2):

The word 'notions' in this context is simply talking about the ideas or views that he has.

> This man <strike>possesses</strike> possessed of some radical notions.

Sidenote - If you want to include the 'of' you must changed the word 'possesses' to 'possessed'.

To the point, the sentence basically means that the man has some very radical ideas about a topic.

The sentence could be re-worded to say:

> The man possessed (of) some radical *ideas/opinions/beliefs*